# Median for continuous distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider a continuous random variable X with probability density function given by $f(x)=cx$ for $1 \le x \le 5$, zero otherwise.  Find the median.

First I calculate the CDF:  $F(x)=cx^2/2$ for $1 \le x \le 5$, zero otherwise.

Now we have to solve for constant c by using the definition of PDF, namely:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1 \implies \frac{c}{2}x^2\Big{|}_1^5=1 \implies c=\frac{1}{12} $$

Then to calculate the median, we set the CDF = 0.5:

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{12}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot x^2 \implies x=\sqrt{12}$$

But the book solution is $\sqrt{13}$.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: I don't think so. Please check my answer.

Comment: The function $F(x)=cx^2/2$ is not the correct CDF here: its value at $1$ should be $0$.

Comment: "First I calculate the CDF" When I do that, I find $F(x)=\frac12c(x^2-1)$ for $x$ in $(1,5)$, $F(x)=0$ for $x\leqslant1$, and $F(x)=1$ for $x\geqslant5$, not what you wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that there is an integration constant when finding the CDF $F(x)$.

Also recall that the CDF should take on the value ZERO when $x$ is from minus infinity to $x=1$ and it must take on the value ONE from $x=5$ to plus infinity. (i.e. the CDF is a non-decreasing function on the support of the density $f(x)$).

If you counter verify, you will see that the above paragraph does not hold for the CDF you found above, in your question.

Reworking on the problem, you should find an appropriate CDF. Simply put: the CDF should be

$$
F(x) = \frac{x^2}{24} - \frac{1}{24}
$$

We see that $F(1) = 0$ and that $F(5) = 1$ indeed.

Finally,

$$
0.5 = \frac{x^2}{24} - \frac{1}{24}
$$

Solving for $x$ yields that the median equals $\sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the integration constant.

Calculating the CDF gives $F(x)=cx^2/2+d$ on $1\leq x\leq 5$, $F(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $F(x)=1$ for $x>1$. Setting $F(1)=0$ and $F(5)=1$, we get $c=1/12$ and $d=-1/24$. The solution for $F(x)=1/2$ is then indeed $\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: I thought you only need integration constant if you are taking an indefinite integral.  My integral is definite:  from 1-5.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: Please see my comment below the question to see why the constant matters.

Comment: user1527227: I've removed my comment, since Rasmus is correct. My oversight (I was moving too quickly) is not carrying through the lower bound on the definite integral. However, its not a "constant of integration" but merely the lower value of the definite integral, i.e., $F(1) = \frac{1}{24}$, so $F(x) = \frac{x^2}{24} - \frac{1}{24}$ thats where the additional term comes from.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys! I also see I could have just changed my limits of integration from 1 to x and that would also work!

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 You may call it however you like. In any case, it's this constant in the integral that one needs to work things out.

Comment: @user1527227 Your're welcome!

Comment: @Rasmus: I agree...I wasn't trying to be pedantic, so sorry if I came across as such. I was relating it to what user1527227 was saying about definite vs. indefinte integration. I wanted to show that you get the same constant even if you apply the fundamental theorem of calculas for definite integrals.

Answer (score 2):

For median $m$:

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{m} f(x) dx = \int\limits_{m}^{+\infty} f(x) dx\\
\int\limits_{1}^{m} f(x) dx = \int\limits_{m}^{5} f(x) dx\\
c \frac{x^2}{2}\Biggr|_{1}^{m} = c \frac{x^2}{2}\Biggr|_{m}^{5}\\
x^2\Biggr|_{1}^{m} = x^2\Biggr|_{m}^{5}\\
m = \sqrt{\frac{1^2 + 5^2}{2}}=\sqrt{13}
$$